# What are the correlations between HEXACO and NEO-PI factors?

Tags: personality

My background is more strongly grounded in the Big 5 model of personality. I'm gradually getting familiar with the HEXACO model of personality. I realise that HEXACO is not just the Big 5 plus honesty-humility. But given that the Big 5 will be many people's frame of reference when learning about the HEXACO, what is a quick summary of how HEXACO and the Big 5 differ.

In particular, what are the correlations between measures of HEXACO and NEO-FFI or NEO-PI (i.e., arguably the most popular big 5 measure)?

Comment: If anyone has a reference for the relationship at the facet level, please share that as well.

Answer (score 6):

Based on n = 290, I found this correlation matrix in Gaughan et al (2012) (I think the adjusted R-squareds are for regression models predicting domain scores from the domains of the other measure; e.g., 50% of variance in honesty-humility was predicted by the five NEO domain scores).

[image: neo hexaco correlations]

Summarising these correlations, focusing on the HEXACO:

- Honesty-humility is most closely related to agreeableness but is not the same
- Emotionality is related to neuroticism, but also quite distinct the correlation is much weaker than would be required to argue it is a similar construct.
- Extraversion is mostly the same in both models, but hexaco extraversion seems to be more related to neuroticism (-) than NEO neuroticism.
- Agreeableness (HEXACO) is moderately related to NEO agreeableness, but there are clearly differences. HEXACO  agreeableness also has a notable correlation with neuroticism (-).
- Conscientiousness is mostly the same in both models.
- Openness is similar in both models, but not massive.

Focusing on the NEO

- Neuroticism is distributed across hexaco emotioanlity, extraversion, and agreeableness

#### So in summary

- HEXACO Extraversion, conscientiousness, and openness can probably be related to a similar interpretative framework as the NEO/Big 5 literature.
- Relating HEXACO to NEO agreeableness and neuroticism is difficult. Using emotionality as a proxy for neuroticism is definitely problematic.

#### Another empirical study

Here was another study I found in Ashton et al (2014) using Big 5 markers.

[image: big 5 and hexaco]

Correlations between honesty-humility and agreeableness were not as strong as above. Also, the negative correlation between neuroticism and extraversion was much smaller.

#### How it is discussed in a paper

I found this paragraph from Dunlop et al (2016) to be a good quick summary of the differences:

> Within the HEXACO model, the Openness, Extraversion, and
>   Conscientiousness factors generally correspond to their Big Five
>   counterparts. The Emotionality and Agreeableness factors of the HEXACO
>   represent rotational variants of Neuroticism and Agreeableness in the
>   Big Five. However, the most prominent difference between the HEXACO
>   and Five Factor model is the addition of the HEXACO Honesty-Humility
>   factor ... (Ashton & Lee, 2007; Ashton, Lee, & de Vries, 2014).

#### References

- Gaughan, E. T., Miller, J. D., & Lynam, D. R. (2012). Examining the utility of general models of personality in the study of psychopathy: A comparison of the HEXACO-PI-R and NEO PI-R. Journal of personality disorders, 26(4), 513.
- Dunlop, P. D., Bourdage, J. S., de Vries, R. E., Hilbig, B. E., Zettler, I., & Ludeke, S. G. (2016). Openness to (reporting) experiences that we never had: Overclaiming as an outcome of the knowledge accumulated through a proclivity for cognitive and aesthetic exploration. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology.
- Ashton, M. C., Lee, K., & de Vries, R. E. (2014). The HEXACO honesty-humility, agreeableness, and emotionality factors a review of research and theory. Personality and Social Psychology Review, 18(2), 139-152.